# How to label scatter point plots from data column in excel

Tags: excel, scatter-plot

I have an Excel spreadsheet and I want to plot data from three columns:  X, Y and L.  The X and Y represent points I want to plot as a scatter plot, and L represents the label (point color, point symbol) that I want applied to each X, Y point.  I see that [How to plot points using their class labels?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15147211/how-to-plot-points-using-their-class-labels) reports a solution for R, but I'd like one for Excel, if possible, preferably using UI rather than VBA.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

With Excel 2013 and later you can add data labels with the option "Value from Cells".

In earlier versions, you need to add each individual data label and give it the cell reference to the cell with the label (edit the label, type a = character, then click the cell with the label text).

This is tedious for charts with many values and can be sped up significantly with a free add-in by Rob Bovey, called the XY Chart Labeler, [download here](http://www.appspro.com/Utilities/ChartLabeler.htm). The tool gives you a UI to insert and place labels.

Once the labels are in place, the file can be distributed to people who don't have the tool. It simply speeds up a manual process.